# Selecting the h2 element based on a clicked parent

Tags: javascript

I have a div called "panel" with multiple child elements, each with a class of poster. Each poster will be a card displaying restaurant information. I want to target the h2 for whichever poster the user clicks on, irrespective of which area of the poster they click. I'm using event delegation on the panel but I'm not sure how to target the h2.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">

  <div class="poster">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class="time">6-7:30PM</p>
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <h2 class="restaurant-title">Restaurant A</h2>
        <h3 class="deal-description">bla bla bla</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="poster">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class="time">2-4:30PM</p>
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <h2 class="restaurant-title">Restaurant B</h2>
        <h3 class="deal-description">bla bla bla</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="poster">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class="time">1-5:30PM</p>
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <h2 class="restaurant-title">Restaurant C</h2>
        <h3 class="deal-description">bla bla bla</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var panel = document.querySelector(".panel");

panel.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

Answer (score 2):

use **[queryselector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** in javascript

```
 function handleClick(){
     var h2=this.querySelector("h2");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9wk7wbm/)

Comment: this solution doesn't update the h2 depending on which poster I click on. it keeps spitting out "restaurant A"

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$(".panel").click(function(){
   var h2 = $(this).find('h2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".poster").click(function(){
       var h2 = $(this).children(".restaurant-title");    
        //alert(h2.context.innerText);
    })
})
```

Example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ar1xawku/
Don't forget include jquery library in your code

Comment: i'm getting the restaurant-title (restaurant A), time (6-7:30PM) , and the deal description (bla bla bla). how do i isolate just "restaurant A"? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out a solution for this, and thought i'd share:

```
$(".poster").click(function(){

    var h2 = $(this).find('h2');

    var restaurantTitle = (h2["0"].innerText);
```